# how to get parents id while fetching child's information - Grails?

Tags: grails, controller

How to access firstname and lastname of user depending on which statusItem is displayed which is the child of the user.

```
class UserAccount implements Serializable {


static transients = ['pass','passConfirm','familyPicTmp', 'familyPicTmpFilename', 'photoTmp', 'photoTmpFilename']
static hasMany = [authorities: Authorisation, memberships:FamilyMembership, progenitorIwi:Family,  politicItems:PoliticItem,
    relationships:Relationship, , agents:UserAccount, media:UserMedia, status:Status]
static mappedBy = [ progenitorIwi:"progenitor",relationships:'relationTo', relationships:'userAccount']
static fetchMode = [memberships:FetchMode.JOIN, agents:FetchMode.JOIN]
static mapping = {
    memberships(lazy:false)
    agents(lazy:false)
}

static belongsTo = [Authorisation]
```

STATUS DOMAIN

```
class Status {
  static belongsTo = [userAccount:UserAccount]
  def String statusMessage
  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated
  def String statusType
```

POLITIC DOMAIN

```
class PoliticItem {

    SystemEntity politicItemName
    UserAccount userAccount

    def String politicItemValue
    def boolean shared = false
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
```

How can we load all the users that belong to all the status on to the politic's views?

Comment: can you clarify your question? probably you need to post your related domains.

Comment: Please check my updated question with all the domains... @Alidad

Comment: The more you clarify your question the more people can help you here.  I am not quite understanding what you are looking for. Are you trying to find users based on their status ? if so userAccount in Status domain is the back reference to the parent.

Comment: I dont know how to do so.. could you please tell me the syntex please.. thanks

Comment: No, When I try to load list of all statuses straight on to status view it loads everything fine expect images wont get displayed and on politic profile I just dont know how to load user info based on status.

Comment: @Alidad please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure which part you dont know. Assuming userAccount has the firstName and lastName field to access them from status try this:

`status` is the instance of your `Status` class. The one you need to get the userAccount off of it.

```
status.userAccount.firstName
```

or

```
status.userAccount.lastName
```

Comment: Massive help here... do you think is there any type of restriction or anything thats restricting images to display even though right image url is showing... @Alidad

Comment: you probably need to open another question for the image with more information related to it.

Comment: I solved it using dynamic finders and syntax given by you... Thanks @Alidad